# How do I put select tag in container that is inside an echo?

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I have this code

```
echo "<select name='edu'>";
```

How do I even put this combo box inside `<div>` or `<p>` for it's position purposes.
For example I want it inside a container with 50% of width.

Comment: echo "<div><select name='edu'>"; .. ?!?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is what you wanted. You can create a `div` container using HTML and then use PHP to `echo` `<select></select>`.

```
<div class="container">
<?php 
  echo '
        <select name="options">
          <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="option-3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        ';
?>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

[name="options"] {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for all intents and purposes appears to be an HTML question, not necessarily PHP, correct? Echo is just printing the HTML block in this case.

```
<div style="width: 800px;">
    <div style="50%;">
        <select name='edu'>Education</select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The 800px is just an arbitrary outer container div tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
echo "<div id='myDiv'><select name='edu'></div>";
```

and if you want your content to be the same width as your div you can add this also.

```
<style>
#myDiv {
width: 50%;
}

#myDiv select {
width: 100%;
}
</style>
```